# Display Selected Value: Bootstrap Select w/ Angular 2

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

HTML:

```
<select formControlName="state" class="form-control" id="state"
   <option *ngFor="let state of stateList">
      {{state}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Typescript:

```
this.stateList = ['AK', 'TX', 'OR'] //etc, all states  

this.myForm= new FormGroup({
  someField: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  state: new FormControl('AL', [Validators.required])
});
```

This code works fine, except that the dropdown does not DISPLAY the selected value, at all. The value IS populated if I output:

```
<pre>{{myForm.get('state').value}}</pre>
```

or

```
<pre>{{myForm.value  | json}}</pre>
```

I can't find a single example of how this works with angular forms. People seem to be using `ngValue` or `ngModel` or `value`, but that does nothing here (Obviously works for direct binding though).

Comment: `new FormControl('AL'`... However there's no AL in your `stateList`.

Comment: @developer033 Thanks for the answer, but all the states are there in practice. I just shortened for the question.

Comment: Also, you must set `[value]="state"` on `<option>`.

Comment: @developer033 I tried that already - just tried again after your answer. It doesn't work or throw errors or change anything at all.

Comment: Just to check.. did you close the `<select>` **tag**? It works in [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CKN0H6FYzElFUOoiuACG?p=preview).

Comment: @developer033 Make an answer with that link, I will accept. Looks like I am ****ing up somewhere else. Really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a little mistake in your `code`:

You must set the `[value]="state"`

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CKN0H6FYzElFUOoiuACG?p=preview)